# Why does Vanellope have a dress?

Tags: wreck-it-ralph

Throughout *Wreck-It Ralph*,  Vanellope did not have a dress, but:

> at the end it's revealed she was intended to be a princess, and thus has a dress

On the outside of her game though,  she is shown without her dress,  in 'normal' clothes. Shouldn't she be shown with a dress on the outside?

Why did she get a dress?

Comment: I believe she had an appearance mod on her "character information" in the database that had been hacked.

Comment: @Thaddeus which was the mod...? The dress?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage You're *both* mods ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor You are all mods (now)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You see her in three different outfits in the movie.

**The way she looks throughout nearly all of the film**

[image: Vanellope wearing her green hoodie and black skirt]

> Vanellope's signature "glitch" outfit is a mint green hoodie with a double-layered brown skirt that resembles the wrapping of a peanut-butter cup (many of the girls have skirts like this), green, white and purple leggings, and small black boots. - http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Vanellope_von_Schweetz

**The box art on the arcade (different jacket, racing gloves, and apparently different *eyes*)**

[image: The arcade cabinet]

> On the side of the Sugar Rush game cabinet, Vanellope can be seen in her royal racing attire which is a teal, orange, and white jumpsuit with brown gloves. In the film's concept art, Vanellope's racing attire comes with a white helmet with a golden crown design detailed onto it. - http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Vanellope_von_Schweetz

**And when the character is reset.**

[image: Her dress]

> As a princess, Vanellope wore a full skirted glittery long-sleeved gown with lacy white gloves. Her gradient pink petticoat is noticeably covered in pink, white and red gumdrops, sprinkled everywhere like beads...Although she dislikes it, she wore it at Calhoun and Felix's wedding as her maid of honor outfit. -http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Vanellope_von_Schweetz

So she has her formal wear, as princess, her *original* royal racing attire, and her *glitch* appearance, which is the one she prefers and uses.

Comment: So why is she not reset to her racing gear

Comment: Maybe because she wasn't currently in a race. You can't expect her to race in that dress.

Comment: tell that to Princesses Peach and Daisy

Comment: I would guess that in the original version of the game that dress appears in a scene that plays when you select her, so it's her "starting outfit" that she sheds to reveal her racer togs.

Answer (score 4):

When Vannelope resets the game (by winning), it also seems to reset her character, including her fancy princess dress. This fits in nicely with her backstory as a tomboy princess *who also happens to be the kingdom's top racer*.

You might want to note that on the console, she's actually wearing a third outfit, some sort of racing jumpsuit

[image]

You can see various versions of this racing jumpsuit in the film's "concept art", as seen in [*The Art of Wreck-it Ralph*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/14553884-the-art-of-wreck-it-ralph)). Her official racing garb and car looked rather more regal in earlier concepts.

[image]

[image]

And there's also some nice early art for differing colour schemes/styles for her princess dress, if that's of interest to you...

[image]

Comment: Where did the second and third images come from?

Comment: Her "original cart" just became King Candy's. Which makes sense since he would have stole it from Vanelope when he hijacked the game.